# XSLT - add prefix for namespace

Tags: xslt

Here's my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sync
    xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" languageCode="en-US" versionID="2.8.0">
    <Data>
        <ID>0001</ID>
        <Text>ABCD</Text>
    </Data>
</Sync>
```

And here's my expected outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Sync xmlns:ns0="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"
      languageCode="en-US"
      versionID="2.8.0">
      <DataArea xmlns:dns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns="">
      <ID>0001</ID>
      <Text>ABCD</Text>
   </DataArea>
</ns0:Sync>
```

My current XSLT as below (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE19N).
There are 2 problems:

1. I have the extra xmlns="" in DataArea element. I only want to add the dns namespace.
2. I cannot add the ns0 prefix for my namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*:Sync">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*:Sync/*:Data">
        <DataArea>
            <xsl:namespace name="dns" select="'http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2'"/>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="/*:Sync/*:Data/*:ID"/>
            </ID>
            <Text>
                <xsl:value-of select="/*:Sync/*:Data/*:Text"/>
            </Text>
        </DataArea>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this return the expected result:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Sync">
    <ns0:Sync xmlns:ns0="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ns0:Sync> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <DataArea xmlns:dns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </DataArea> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. I am not sure why you need  the `xmlns:dns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2"` declaration; it's not being used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly. For your question, to be honest I have no idea, the guy who is working at the receiving end insists to have it there